# How to find the order of $\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)}\frac{1}{\log(x-t)}\mathrm{dt}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

I'm trying to prove that

$$ \int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)}\frac{1}{\log(x-t)}\mathrm{dt} \sim \frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{\log(x)^2}, $$
that is,

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)}\frac{1}{\log(x-t)}\mathrm{dt}}{x^2/\log(x)^2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Numerically it seems to be right, as for $x=10^{20}$ the above expression gives $\approx 0.523$, and for $x=10^{100}$ it is $\approx 0.504$. (I calculated using Python.)

However, I didn't find a way to effectively tackle this problem. Substituting $u:=t/x$ in the integral, as $\mathrm{d}u = 1/x~ \mathrm{d}t$ one obtain

\begin{align} \int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)}\frac{1}{\log(x-t)}\mathrm{dt} &= \int_{2/x}^{1-2/x}\frac{xu}{\log(x)+\log(u)}\frac{x}{\log(x) + \log(1-u)}\mathrm{du} \\
&= \frac{x^2}{\log(x)}\int_{2/x}^{1-2/x}\frac{u}{\left(1+\frac{\log(u)}{\log(x)}\right)\left(1+\frac{\log(1-u)}{\log(x)}\right)}\mathrm{du}, \end{align}

but here I'm basically stuck. The [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) doesn't seem to work either.

Any tips would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: are you sure about this bound?

Comment: @tired Not exactly. All I know is that $$ \int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)}\frac{1}{\log(x-t)}\mathrm{dt} \asymp \frac{x^2}{\log(x)^2}, $$
but numerically it seems to be $\sim 1/2$. It's a guess :P

Comment: We may notice that $\frac{d}{da}\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t^a\,dt}{\log(t)\log(x-t)} = \int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t^a\,dt}{\log(x-t)}$, and the last integral should be easier to study.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a clever symmetry trick:
$$I(x)=\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)\log(x-t)}\,dt = \int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{x-t}{\log(t)\log(x-t)}\,dt \tag{1}$$
giving:
$$ I(x) = \frac{x}{2}\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{dt}{\log(t)\log(x-t)}= x\int_{2}^{\frac{x}{2}}\frac{dt}{\log(t)\log(x-t)}\tag{2}$$
where the last integral in concentrated around the right endpoint of the integration range, hence it can be approximated pretty well by:
$$ \frac{x}{\log(x-2)}\int_{2}^{x/2}\frac{dt}{\log(t)} \tag{3}$$
where the logarithmic integral has a well-known asymptotic expansion.

Comment: (+1) Damn you! I was writing it just now! :D well done however.

Comment: Wow, that's a really beautiful trick! I think I would have never thought it by myself hahaha. Well done!!