# New bounds for $\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)}\frac{1}{\log(x-t)}\mathrm{dt}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, approximation

I have revised [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509934/how-to-find-the-order-of-int-2x-2-fract-logt-frac1-logx-t-mat?rq=1) interesting stackexchange question with solution,  $\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)}\frac{1}{\log(x-t)}\mathrm{dt} \tag{1}$
in the form of this approximation :

$\frac{x}{\log(x-2)}\int_{2}^{x/2}\frac{dt}{\log(t)} \tag{2}$

now the rational it seems behind using $\frac{x}{\log(x-2)}$ outside the LogIntegral seems to ensure a bound in one direction but I'd like to get tighter bounds in both directions.

The question is how do I 'tighten' up the bounds on this particular approximation (2)?

What are the strategies for going about this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

To help get things along since posting the question a couple of days ago, I've considered a loose bound as a first attempt.  Maybe somebody can improve or tighten the bounds by some other method.

Using $\frac{x}{\log(x-2)}$ (as suggested by @Jack D'Aurizio ) outside the Log Integral one bound can be established and looking at the plot of $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ and $\frac{x}{\log(x-t)}$, $\frac{x}{\log(x/2)}$ ensures the other bound such that:

$\frac{x}{\log(x-2)}\int_{2}^{x/2}\frac{dt}{\log(t)}<\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{t}{\log(t)}\frac{1}{\log(x-t)}\mathrm{dt}<\frac{x}{\log(x/2)}\int_{2}^{x-2}\frac{dt}{\log(t)}$

[image: w]